# How to get value from a column what has maximum count in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I understand the MAX function returns a maximum value from a given column for a numeric column. I want to return the maximum count of a column. The below table has two columns maker, product.

```
maker    product      
A        Printer   
B        Laptop        
B        Laptop      
A        Printer 
A        Monitor
A        Printer
A        Scanner
```

But when I run the query '''select maker, max(type) from table group by maker;  ''' I am getting the result as

```
maker    product      
A        Monitor   
B        Laptop
```

I want which product has a maximum count with respect to the maker like below.

```
maker  product      
A      Printer   
B      Laptop
```

Note: As maker count differs, we can't set a common number in Having clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `RANK()` window function:

```
select t.maker, t.product
from (
  select maker, product, 
    rank() over (partition by maker order by count(*) desc) rn
  from tablename 
  group by maker, product
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/peoPUMUhR6PhrH4TBR8TMv/0).
Results:

```
| maker | product |
| ----- | ------- |
| A     | Printer |
| B     | Laptop  |
```

Answer (score 3):

In PostgreSQL, the simplest solution is to use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(maker)
       maker, product
FROM atable
GROUP BY maker, product
ORDER BY maker, count(*) DESC;
```

Comment: No need for the subquery: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/peoPUMUhR6PhrH4TBR8TMv/1